# How to send text file through socket using WinSock2 and fopen_s() in C

Tags: c, sockets, fopen, winsock2

A lot of the examples that I came across uses fopen but Visual Studio 2013 doesn't like fopen and suggested fopen_s() instead. I got the sockets on both the server side and client side to connect and it was able to send messages like strings over the socket. However send() and recv() uses char buffers but fopen_s() uses a FILE type. I'm having trouble making these functions work together to send from server and receive to client. The program does run without runtime errors but nothing gets written in output.txt.

Sending part of server:

```
//Send data from log.txt
FILE *log;
char buff[2024];
errno_t err = fopen_s(&log, "C:\\Users\\amooc\\Desktop\\log.txt", "r+");
if (err <= 0){
    puts("can't open \n");
}
int bytes = send(new_socket, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
if (bytes <= 0){
    fclose(log);
    puts("sent not successful");
}
else{
    printf("sent completed %d", err);
}
/*
message = "12345678ASDLJFA WJR OWJE FAWJ ;AMFJ FWERF9";
int ret = send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
ret = send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR){
    printf("socket error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
else{
    printf("sent\n");
}*/
printf("done\n");
closesocket(s);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
```

Receiving part of cilent:

```
//Receive data from log.txt and write data to output.txt
FILE *log;
char buff[2024];
errno_t err = fopen_s(&log, "C:\\Users\\amooc\\Desktop\\output.txt", "a");

int bytes = recv(s, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
if (bytes <= 0){
    fclose(log);
    puts("receive not successful");
}
else{
    printf("receive completed %d", bytes);
}
puts(buff);
fclose(log);

printf("done\n");
closesocket(s);
WSACleanup();
return 0;
```

Comment: You are neither reading from nor writing to the file. `fopen()` and friends don't do that. Keep reading.

Comment: Even on Visual Studios, If you are setting your compiler target to use C, then fopen/fclose etc are all fine.  They are, and have been part of the C standard for many years.